# Touch scrolling on Netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans, touchscreen

I've just installed Netbeans on my Surface Pro and got everything set up (larger font sizes ftw) but was wondering if there's any way to scroll through the text editor using the touch screen? At the moment, swiping up or down just selects the text/code. I've tried Googling and all sorts of keyboard/touch combinations and nothing works.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Right now I think you can't force netbeans to handle native scrolling, but there is a quite handy workaround:

Download "TouchMe Gesture Studio" from the Windows Store: http://apps.microsoft.com/windows/de-de/app/touchme-gesture-studio/740d3578-ddb4-4f74-b489-5a3782cb7607

This will give you the possibility to define your own multi touch gestures. As I already said you will not be able to override the one finger swipe action. But you can use another swipe gesture (e.g. 2 finger swipe) and bind it to the scrolling event of the mouse wheel. Especially this will work in netbeans as well as in any other application.